# How do I change the title of a link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

Here is the code I have:

```
      $('#link').attr("href",link) 
      $('#link').text(text)
```

How do I change the title of a link using jQuery? I'm correctly changing the url, but I can't edit the text, what am I doing wrong?

```
<a id="link" href="" target="_blank">text</a>



 $('#link').attr("href",data[1].url) 
 $('#link').attr("title",data[1].title) 

<a href="http://link.com">title</a>
```

I'm tring to simply change 2 things:

1. url
2. title (as show above)

I'm able to change the link, but the title won't change. I'm selecting the wrong trhing. Therefor is there a way to list all attr available to me? Or are you able to help me change the text title above?

Either answer is acceptable.

```
        <div id="highlight" class="topicHighlight hero1">
            <h3 id="h3">hero_1_large_text</h3>
            <p id="p"></p>
                <span id="coverTextSpan">hero_1_small_text</span>
                <a id="link" href="url" target="_blank">text</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: maybe u'd better write a ; after ur code

Comment: @zhzhzhh: Semicolon statement terminators are actually optional in JavaScript.

Comment: @mu is too short: I know,but did u find what's the reason cause that problem?I don't find that yet.

Comment: related: [Change Link text with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47221792/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function:

```
$('#link').html(text);
```

or  , if you are talking about the title attribute:

```
$('#link').attr('title','some title');
```

Comment: I just want to change the word title: <a href="http://link.com">title</a> how do I do this?

Comment: I think you are making a confusion between the title attribute and the html of a link tag... see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp .... so, if you want to change the link`s html (the displayed text) you need to change the innerHTML property for that link (jquery offers a  wrapped function : see http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1):

you can try this javascript only.

```
document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = "new title";
```

i think this will surly helpful to you..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the HTML() method to change the content of the anchor tag.
Here is the [link](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If all these answers don't work for you then you should check:

1. What element are you selecting and see if it's the correct one
2. What variable are you assigning to the title(data[1].title)

I recommend using firebug in firefox or using the dev console in google chrome, anduse the console.log() function to log things so that you don't have to alert() them all the time.