# Change Link text with CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I want to change my link Text with CSS, but it doesn't work.

```css
a.testclass {
  display: none;
}

a.testclass:after {
  content: 'new text';
}
```

```html
<a class="testclass;" href="someurl.com"> CHANGE THIS HERE </a>
```

Display none works for me but not the new text.

Comment: there is an unnecessary ; at the end of your classname

Comment: _“Display none works for me”_ - not with the code you have shown, because you have the classname wrong in the HTML. _“but not the new text”_ - oh but yes, that works as well - but you don’t _see_ it, _because_ you set the whole element to display:none.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can hide the original text by using `font-size:0;` then adding the original font size back to your after:

```css
a.testclass {
  font-size:0;
}

a.testclass:after {
  content: 'new text';
  font-size:16px;         /* original font size */
}
```

```html
<a class="testclass" href="someurl.com"> CHANGE THIS HERE </a>
```

Comment: Do you know if this has accessibility implications?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky https://tink.uk/accessibility-support-for-css-generated-content/.  I guess as you are only hiding the original text with font size - screen readers will read both content and not know one is meant to be hidden

Answer (score 2):

Use `font-size: 0` to hide the original text. To restore the original size use `font-size: initial`. You won't need to care about the original value.

```css
a.testclass {
  font-size: 0;
}

a.testclass:after {
  content: 'new text';
  font-size: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
a.testclass:after{
content: 'new text';
}
```

```html
<a class="testclass" href="someurl.com"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```css
a.testclass {
  visibility:hidden;
}
a.testclass:before {
  content: 'new text';
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<a class="testclass" href="example.com">Link</a>
```