# Issue with changing the title of a link using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to change the title of a link using JQuery. Basically my current theme has an issue identifying something as a URL even though I keyed in www.hotmail.com. I would like to:

(1) Get it to recognize that it is a link to www.hotmail.com

(2) Change the name www.hotmail.com to Click Here

I have tried to implement what was mentioned in this thread but have been unsuccessful ([How do I change the title of a link using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226592/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-a-link-using-jquery)).

I was able to get the link to direct to www.hotmail.com upon clicking but the text does not change to Click Here.

My code:

```
var href = jQuery('p.item-property').html();
var link = "<a href='"+href+"' target='_blank'>"+href+"</a>";

jQuery('p.item-property').replaceWith(link);

$('p.item-property').text('Click Here');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector identifies the elements corresponding the elements you have replaced with `link`. You wanted to change the `text` of `link` instead:

```
var href = jQuery('p.item-property').html();
var link = "<a href='"+href+"' target='_blank'>"+href+"</a>";

jQuery('p.item-property').replaceWith(link);

$(link).text('Click Here');
```

but it is even better to set the correct `text` at initialization

```
var href = jQuery('p.item-property').html();
var link = "<a href='"+href+"' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>";

jQuery('p.item-property').replaceWith(link);
```

Comment: I have been trying to change the p.item-property to a different item `'#c27-single-listing > section > div.profile-cover-content.reveal.reveal_visible > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > div'` but have been getting an error message `Error 404: The page your are looking for cannot be found.` Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Have posted my query here if it is unclear --> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978304/using-javascript-to-select-div-leads-to-page-not-found-error). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As you are replacing the `p.item-property`, it doesn't exists anymore thus text is not changed.

I would recommend you to create element using [`jQuery(html, attributes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) which can be easily manipulated.

```js
var href = jQuery('p.item-property').html();

//Create element using jQuery
var link = $('<a>', {
  href: href,
  text: href //<== You can directly set here 'Click Here'
});

//Replace the element
jQuery('p.item-property').replaceWith(link);

//Update the text
link.text('Click Here');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="item-property">http://link.com</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure why I was not able to get this to work. Thank you for your help.