# Using Javascript to select div leads to page not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404

I managed to get help on another thread for changing the title and link of an element using JavaScript ([Issue with changing the title of a link using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976270/issue-with-changing-the-title-of-a-link-using-jquery)).

I have tried implementing the technique there to another element on my website but am instead met with an error `Error 404: The page your are looking for cannot be found.`

Thus, while this code works in isolation:

```
var href = jQuery('#_tab_1 > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.pf-body > ul > li:nth-last-child(1) > p.item-property').html();
var link = "<a href='"+href+"' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>";
jQuery('#_tab_1 > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.pf-body > ul > li:nth-last-child(1) > p.item-property').replaceWith(link);
```

The following code leads to the error mentioned above.

```
var href = jQuery('#_tab_1 > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.pf-body > ul > li:nth-last-child(1) > p.item-property').html();
var link = "<a href='"+href+"' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>";
jQuery('#_tab_1 > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.pf-body > ul > li:nth-last-child(1) > p.item-property').replaceWith(link);

var href2 = jQuery('#c27-single-listing > section > div.profile-cover-content.reveal.reveal_visible > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > div').html();
var link2 = "<a href='"+href2+"' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>";
jQuery('#c27-single-listing > section > div.profile-cover-content.reveal.reveal_visible > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > div').replaceWith(link2);
```

Attached is the link to the html code I am targeting ([Link](https://jsfiddle.net/u3uL4mcm/1/)). Note that the  link only reflects the html related to the javascript code that I can't get working ie. `href2`. I had not posted the segment that href was targeting as it might get too messy. My purpose is to replace `www.hotmail.com` with the words `Click Here`, but the user should be able to select `Click Here` and it would direct them to `www.hotmail.com`. Also, because I had to select only the relevant portions of the html, the selector you view in the link would be different from what is stated in my code above.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check the content of `href2`. Is it a valid URL? Does the resource defined by `href2` exist?

Comment: The error is telling you the page you have requested is not found. How do you reproduce the error? Are you clicking somehow on link2?

Comment: Can you please show your html code

Comment: seems like your selectors are too complicated. try giving the item you want to select \ replace a specific `class` or specific `id` and just use

`jQuery('#replace-later').replaceWith(link)

same for the second selector.

I think most of your problems are probably related to selectors not finding actual page elements

Comment: @firefirehelphelp You should keep comment replies in the comment section unless it changed something in your original question or code.

please replace all your copy\paste comments with the text in the question you added. No reason for it to not work with a shorter, more specific selector. if you want to include a code snippet (with at least javascript + html), that could very much help us help you :-) you can take the jsfiddle you added as a comment to YouneL and just incorporate it in your question. try and remove the unnecessary code from that jsfiddle (unrelated to the problem).

Comment: @firefirehelphelp sorry for the comments, I'm really just trying to help you get the help you need :-)

can you please explain some more what are you trying to do?
replace the href of the link with another one?
please treat this question as an individual one, unrelated to your previous question

Comment: @Thatkookooguy Not a problem at all, appreciate the feedback! I have tried amending it to a more specific selector but it would not work. Can you please help me see my code? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u3uL4mcm/1/). My purpose is to replace `www.hotmail.com` with the words Click Here, but the user should be able to select Click Here and it would direct them to www.hotmail.com. Note that the above html only reflects the html for the javascript code that I can't get working ie. `href2`. I had not posted the segment that `href` was targeting as it might get too messy. Thank you.

Comment: @YouneL I have uploaded my HTML code here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u3uL4mcm/1/). Note that the above html only reflects the html that I can't get working ie. href2. I had not posted the segment that `href` was targeting as it might get too messy. Thank you.

Comment: @Andreas I am pretty sure my href2 is a valid URL as the output is referencing the same thing as href. The paths look different but their output is the same. Thank you.

Comment: @LajosArpad I reproduced the error by inputting the above code into my wordpress theme's custom Javascript section and clicked Update and it automatically brings me to a page that says `Error 404: The page your are looking for cannot be found.` Thank you.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem. The linked fiddle doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that does what you want.
Notice that you can use either a class (for multiple elements) or an id (for a singular element).

Basically, I used several commands to do what you wanted:

- `each()` - should do the following function for each element found by the selector. `this` will refer to the DOM element
- `text()` - return the text (without html) for that item
- `replaceWith()` - will replace the element with whatever you want

in this example, every item with the class `should-become-link` will become a link after 2 seconds (because of the `setTimeout`).
The original text inside the element will be used as the new `href` value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var element = $('.should-become-link');
    element.each(function(index) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var currentText = $this.text();

      $this.replaceWith(
        `<a href="${currentText}" target="_blank">Click Here</a>`
      );
    });
  }, 2000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons medium button-outlined should-become-link">
  https://www.hotmail.com
</div>

<div><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">shouldn't change!</a></div>
<div><a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">shouldn't change!</a></div>
<div><a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">shouldn't change!</a></div>
<div><a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">shouldn't change!</a></div>
<div><a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">shouldn't change!</a></div>

<div class="buttons medium button-outlined should-become-link">
  https://www.google.com
</div>
```

and here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/vpgxwj)

Comment: If this didn't answer your question entirely, please point me to what is missing and I'll edit my answer

Comment: Hi Thatkookooguy, I tried implementing your solution but was not able to get it to work. Can you please help me see in the following link what is wrong? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cbum98tj/1/). Thank you

Comment: @firefirehelphelp you just forgot to include jQuery as a dependency. Here is a fixed [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mnkya03/). If you want only the Hotmail button to change, give it a unique class or ID and add that to the selector

Comment: Hi Thatkookooguy, I have tried amending the code, please see [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5mnkya03/4/). Can you please help me with the following (1) When I paste the above code into the Custom Code section of my Wordpress theme and select update it still doesn't change `www.hotmail.com` to `Click Here`. (2) Also, I don't believe I can give the www.hotmail.com a unique class or ID because this is generated by the wordpress theme I am using? (3) Also, when I access the link I provided using internet explorer, it does not change the text to Click Here. Is there a reason for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:eq()` Selector to select the 4th `li` and then replace its content:

HTML:

```
 <div id="buttons medium button-outlined">https://www.hotmail.com</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var href2 = $('.container li:eq(3) > .buttons').html();
var link2 = "<a href='"+href2+"' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>";
$('.container li:eq(3) > .buttons').replaceWith(link2);
```

Working Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u3uL4mcm/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems like you changed the name of the div to `link2`. I tried to get it to work using the original name of the div but was unsuccessful. Could you please help me out? Attached are my workings --> [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u3uL4mcm/4/) Thank you.

Comment: Hi YouneL, thanks for the reply. I have entered your code into the javascript section of my wordpress theme -->[link](https://imgur.com/a/ecave). However, it still does not change the `www.hotmail.com` to `Click Here` --> [link](https://imgur.com/a/SNYhq). Has this got anything to do with including Jquery as a dependency? If so, could you please let me know how to modify my code to include this? Thank you.

Comment: How many container class do you have in your html code, and please show javascript errors may help to resolve your prb